# How can I override Spring repository methods to add a constraint on a boolean column?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am reading Spring In Action (6th edition) to get myself into learning the Spring framework and I have a doubt about how to override the default behavior of Spring JPA when declaring repositories.

As far as I have read so far, I can declare repository methods such as `findByName()` and let Spring magically implement the method. Now, let's imagine that the records in the repository have a boolean column named `enabled`, and I want the application to only process the records with `enabled = TRUE`. I know I could declare methods such as `findByNameAndEnabledIsTrue()` but I wonder whether there is a way to make, for example, `findByName()` take into account this flag.

So far I tried to override the method, but it doesn't seem to work, since there's actual no method defined at compile time:

```
@Override
List<Customer> findByName(@Param("name") String name) {
    return findByNameAndEnabledIsTrue(name);
}
```

How could this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `@Query` to explicitly define the query using JPQL rather than relies on spring-data to generate the query based on the query method name. In this way, you can get back the total control to define what the query you exactly want to have . Something like :

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

  @Query("select u from Customer c where c.name = :name and c.enabled = true")
  List<Customer> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

This is the way I prefer. Simple, flexible and much less magic.

If you insist do not want to write JPQL, you can implement a custom repository (See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior)) , and inject the `CustomerRepository` into this custom repository and reuse it method. Something like :

```java
interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> , CustomizedCustomerRepository {

    List<Customer> findByNameAndEnabledIsTrue();   
}

interface CustomizedCustomerRepository {
  void findByName(String name);
}


class CustomizedCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomizedCustomerRepository {

  @Autowired
  private CustomerRepository repo;

  @Override
  List<Customer> findByName(String name) {
    return repo.findByNameAndEnabledIsTrue(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about the existence of @Query. That would do the trick!